# Printing of PHP Forms

Tags: php

All,
I have some forms that my users fill out some forms that have text boxes, selects on it etc. I'd like to be able to print these forms out then but obviously don't want the form elements etc. I'd like to just print the text for each form object.

Do I have to create a brand new PHP file to handle the printing of a form or can I do something with PHP/CSS etc?

Please let me know what options I have to do this. I'd ideally not like to code a whole new page to mimic the form just to print it.

Thanks

Comment: Try CSS print media queries. Take a look here http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media0 and here http://www.joshuawinn.com/css-print-media-query/

Comment: You can use html_entity_decode. I use it for exporting forms to csv...http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using CSS's `@media` declaration, you can specify print-specific styles:

```
@media print {
  input, select {
      border: none;
  }
}
```

Obviously, you'd want to go a little more in depth than that, but it should get you started

**Documentation**

CSS @media on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/@media

Comment: Can I just declare that in any CSS file and then when I print the file it takes this into account?

Comment: Yes, but if your other CSS is NOT specific to a media type (if you don't use `media=""` in your `<link>` tags, for example), then that CSS will also apply to printing. You can either add the `media` property to your style inclusions, or your print styles will have to override any other styles that might affect given elements. You'll have to do a lot of testing, and more than several test prints.